# How can I save the initial background color of a section, change it, and come back to it after a while?

Tags: javascript

I have a section in my HTML.If I click on it, I would like using javascript to count the number of clicks on the section in the first 2 seconds after I only clicked once, and at each click to add 2 seconds until my section will come back at it's initial background color.

My "color" variable takes the initial value of the background, in my case: red, but when I change my background color to purple, it also changes, I think it's because it is a reference, I tried 3 ways to avoid this problem but without success.

```
    window.onload=function(){
        StopProp();
        Schimbare();
    }

    var color,clickuit=0,myvar;

    function Schimbare(){
        var x=document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];

        x.onclick=function(){
            color=this.style.background;
            this.style.background="purple";
            alert(color);
            clickuit++;
            if(clickuit==1){
                setTimeout(Numar,2000);
            }
        }
    }

    function Numar(){
        if(clickuit==1) Back();
        else{
                alert(clickuit);
                clickuit--;
                setTimeout(Numar,2000);
        }
     }

     function Back(){
            var x=document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];
            alert(color);
     }
```

Comment: yes, after 2 seconds, if only one click takes place

Answer (score 2):

You set color variable each time you click the section. You must change line

```
color=this.style.background;
```

to

```
if(!color) color=this.style.background;
```

P.S.
Please do not use "alert". use console.log()